# Why isn't my database working in this Python/Django app?

Tags: python, mysql, django, shell

I'm trying to complete the Django tutorial, and everything in my code is working until I try to save and print the instance variables of my object.

Here's the code for my class (this is in the models.py file of my app):

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Then I enter this into the terminal:

```
$ python manage.py sql polls
```

Which returns this output:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE `polls_question` (

`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`question_text` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`pub_date` datetime NOT NULL

)
;
CREATE TABLE `polls_choice` (
`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`question_id` integer NOT NULL,
`choice_text` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`votes` integer NOT NULL
)
;

ALTER TABLE `polls_choice` ADD CONSTRAINT `question_id_refs_id_f3f98eca` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `polls_question` (`id`);

COMMIT;
```

Then I enter this into my terminal:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

Which returns this:

```
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Then I enter this the terminal to start the python shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

And here's the input/output inside the terminal:

```
In [1]: from polls.models import Question, Choice

In [2]: Question.objects.all()
Out[2]: []

In [3]: from django.utils import timezone

In [4]: q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())

In [5]: q.save
Out[5]: <bound method Question.save of <Question: Question object>>
#tutorial does not show this above line appearing

In [6]: q.id
#tutorial says I should get an output from this
```

My questions:

1)  Why am I seeing "< bound method Question.save of >"?

2)  Why don't I get any output when I call the object's id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Model.save is a method

You should run:

```
q.save()
```

Typing q.save in the console only prints the string representation of  the method.

Because you never saved the model object to the database, the model object does not have a id.

Comment: Thank you!  Glad all the typing was worth it!